# How can I select the optimal radius value in order to obtain the best normal estmation results

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, normals

I'm running a model-scene match between a set of point clouds in order to test the matching results.

The match is based on 3D features such as normals and point feature histogram.

I'm using the normal estimation of point cloud library (pcl) to compute the histogram after I'd resampled the point cloud of both model and scene.

My question is, how can I test the accuracy of selecting different radius values in the nearest-neighbor estimation step.

I need to use that values for normal estimation, resampling and histogram in objects such as cup/knife/hummer etc.

I tried to visualize those objects using the pcl visulizer with different radius values and choosing which one that gives correct normals (In terms of how perpendicular were the normals orientation to the surfaces).

But I think that this visual testing is not enough and I would like to know if there are some empiric ways to estimate the optimal radius value.

I would appreciate any suggestion or help ,share your thoughts :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start from a ground test: create a point cloud from a mesh using the mesh normals (using CloudCompare for example), then load it twice: once with full data (including normals) and once without normals.

Rebuild normals using the search radius to be tested then you can directly compare de obtained normals with the one extracted from the mesh...